# Script PLSQL developer run in python jupyter notebook

Tags: sql, mysql, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, plsqldeveloper

I have the problem with my script. The script works good, but not for big script. I would like to use big SQL script with left join , inner join and etc. but after this script does not work. Why Can you help me, What I have to change in script or What script can i use? Thank you so much

```
import cx_Oracle

connection=cx_Oracle.connect("dw1","dw2","//local1/DW3")
cursor=connection.cursor()
rs = cursor.execute("select*from tab t where t.date)>'1.12.2023'")

for row in rs:
    print(row)
    
%load_ext sql
%sql oracle+cx_oracle://dw1:dw2@local/?service_name=DW3
        
%sql select*from tab t where t.number=1
```

Comment: Is it sql or mysql? the formatting matters.  If its just Mysql, look into MySQL Workbench as it can help you format and validate your statements, as well as do right click operations.  But as far as joins, check it out over here at this link to see what type of join you want to make :
https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join.asp

Comment: it is plsql developer, but i know that how work left join, inner join and etc. but when i use sql script with left join it does not work . for example when i use this "select * from tab t left join tab2 t2 on t2.num1=t.num1 where t.number=1 instead of select*from tab t where t.number=1 it does not work

Comment: Does not work as in nothing pulls up at all, it throws an error, or it doesn't pull up all the results you expect?  Also, could your data contain NULL values ?

Comment: terminates the session , i do not know why, Do i need enought big RAM or?

Comment: is this method good? or is there any other way?

Comment: It is possible, if a big querry sometimes ram can help, although you are doing a "select * from table" and do you really need everything?  If there are columns you don't need, just lists the ones that you do need instead of the * and it will pull less data (only the needed data) and run better.

Comment: Could it also be a timeout instead of lack of ram?  Perhaps the larger querry takes longer than is allowed so it errors out early?

Comment: A side comment: Use [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) instead of the older cx_Oracle.

Comment: with oracledb i have the issue in thin mode , DPY-3015: password verifier type 0x939 is not supported by python-oracledb in thin mode . I do not know how solve and change thin mode